# Request to add keyboard navigation to the lists of questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, navigation, keyboard-shortcuts

Can the list of questions be responsive to using the up and down-arrow keys for navigation?

http://duckduckgo.com uses this method for choosing an item from their results page, and it works very well.  Use you arrow-keys on this page for an example:  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sql-server+rocks

Answer (score 3):

Install the [Official keyboard shortcuts](https://stackapps.com/q/2567) and you can use <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> to navigate through question lists, as well as many things besides:

[image: screenshot of the keyboard shartcuts help overlay]

Note that by using <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd>, the arrow keys are still free to move the page itself (as opposed to the post selector); I use the arrow keys to view the top bar if it has scrolled out of view, for example.

Comment: I assume there is a reason `j` and `k` where chosen over the up and down arrows?

Comment: @MaxVernon: Those are the VIM shortcuts for up and down. GMail uses the same shortcuts. Up and down let you scroll the page itself still.